# What is the correct mathematical approach to this linkage problem?

Tags: actuator, linkage

I have a linear actuator with 52 millimeters of travel. I have a set of linkages with specific dimensions as shown in the images below, to which this actuator will be attached.

[image: bones image one]

The REF dimension is one of the constrained parameters and is supposed to be 219 mm, but I can't get that level of granularity with Solvespace at this zoom level and it's close enough to use in this reference.

The 50 mm dimension on the left is variable and is one of the values I seek via mathematics. The 180° angle was necessary to get Solvespace to move the components in the manner needed to create these images, although the linkage composed of the 50 and 120 figures will eventually be one piece with the measurements determined by this query.

[image: bones image two]

The above image shows the objective after the travel of the actuator has reached the maximum extension. The REF figure of 109.91 (110) is provided by Solvespace as the distance when the two links (120 and 116) are co-linear. As before, the 50 mm measurement is arbitrary and variable.

[image: bones image three]

This image shows my first attempt to model the actuator. The previous 50 mm dimension has been shortened to 40 mm and two additional links have been added, both of them at 25 mm length. These are also arbitrary and is an attempt to get in the ballpark without knowing the correct mathematical workflow.

The actuator is represented by the REF 99.45 figure on the left.

I realized after viewing this image for the purpose of posting that one of the links could have been omitted for clarity. As the actuator extends, the REF 99.45 figure would approach 152 at full travel and the H 25 line also extends downward. The H 25 line could have been omitted, but I'm also working on this design in such a way as to mirror the linkage. The H 25 line will be duplicated to the left in the real-world construct.

I have 120 mm of space between the left and right linkage assemblies, which would be fine if the 50 mm remained and allows even more room with the current 40 mm dimension. Shorter lengths are not a complication for that portion of the linkage.

[image: bones image four]

This is the previous linkage approximation when positioned for the objective. The goal is achieved when the actuator reaches REF 126.43, but the desired figure is 152, starting at the previously noted 100 mm drawing.

As best as I can determine, the 40 mm figure and the angled 25 mm figure (in the third image) are the two dimensions to be adjusted to achieve the travel within the constraints. The angled 25 mm figure becomes vertical in the final image, but that's coincidental.

I did well in school in trigonometry, even did well in calculus, but can't apply my mathematical abilities after all these years and determine the workflow to solve this problem.

I'm hoping this doesn't come across as a homework problem, although it's a problem I'm trying to solve from home. It's part of a makerspace construction for extensible wing bones:

[image: bones panel]

The center panel will hold the actuator. When the dimensions are determined the lower "bones" will be changed out with newly cut pieces and the intermediary links will also be installed.

It's important to have the actuator travel of 52 mm as a critical part of this build. The actuator has built-in limit switches, allowing the operator to flip a DPDT switch to either side and not fear for destroying the build or burning out the motor. Too little extension of the bones at full actuator extension is undesirable for cosmetic reasons.

I'm hoping the math is going to be simple enough to understand, but the brain cells just aren't cutting it lately. The original plan was to use bicycle cables and housing to create movement, but in such a small area the friction and necessary sharp bends would not work well. I then switched my alleged mind over to using pulleys, but managed to squeeze out this design above as a preferable solution.

With 225 pound load capacity on the actuator, I believe there will be enough power to move the linkage without an excessive load on the motor.

In summary, how can I calculate the lengths of the links (currently at 40 mm and 25 mm) in order to get the desired movement from 52 mm of actuator travel?

Comment: I'm finding it hard to narrow down the problem you want to solve here.  Are you looking for the general math to describe the motion of the linkages?

Comment: I'm going to clarify my omission in the body of the question. Thanks for pointing out my obfuscation.

Comment: I designed a 6 bar linkage before for a school project.  I sadly don't remember much about our technique; besides that it was basically all numerical.  We had a huge spreadsheet that essentially calculated the movement of each linkage as a function of driving linkage angle; and then we would just change parameters and see how our outputs changed.  Also worth noting that if you're trying to break the problem down into digestable parts; a 6-bar linkage like this basically works out to be two 4-bar linkages in series; the output of the first is the input of the second.

Comment: I had considered the spreadsheet route, but lack the foundation math with which to start. Using Solvespace bypasses a good bit of that, but it's so much of a hit-and-miss or trial-and-error process as to be frustrating.

Comment: And sadly, we never quite got past the "hit and miss" aspect, even with our spreadsheet.  You still had to mess with values and check outputs.  We also had a 3-D model that was able to do a similar thing visually; but that was annoying to get working.

Comment: An app call "MotionGen" is absolutely wonderful for linkage design - make sure to watch the tutorials to fully understand the interface and different modes first: http://www.stonybrook.edu/commcms/motiongen/ You might want to use an android emulator if you don't have a tablet, as it's a bit fiddly on a phone screen.

Comment: @JonathanRSwift, thanks for the lead. I have access to an iOS tablet of good size on which I'll install the app. Even though my objective is to have the math, I think that might be an unrealistic goal and I should instead focus to solve the linkage in any way possible.

Comment: Four bar linkages aren't typically designed using explicit mathematics - have a read of this: http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/cookbook/machine/linkages/linkage_design.html

Comment: It appears that there may not be a mathematical solution to this problem. I'm unable to fathom the four-bar approach even with the simulators available. The motiongen app is similar to the method I used with Solvespace, and I've already learned more of Solvespace than of motiongen. I had considered that Fusion360 would be a resource, but I know less of that program in this context.

Comment: If the answer is found via hit-and-miss, should this question be closed as solved, even though the question is about the math and not about the ultimate solution?